# Webpack Compilation with Postcss fail because not find scss file in library in node_modules

Tags: angular, webpack, postcss, postcss-loader, postcss-import

This is my project structure:

```
node_modules
dist
config
  - webpack.common.js
  - webpack.dev.js
  - webpack.prod.js
  - webpack.test.js
src
  - app
    - app-routing.module.ts
    - app.component.html
    - app.component.scss
    - app.component.ts
    - app.module.ts
    - index.ts
  - index.html
  - main.browser.ts
  - polyfills.browser.ts
angular.json
package.json
postcss.config.js
tsconfig.json
tsconfig.webpack.json
webpack.config.js
```

When I try to compile or build the project with yarn it's failing because it doesn't find a scss file in the node_modules:

[image]

In fact, the scss file exits:

[image]

The file belongs to angular [flex layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

Below is the `app.components.scss` that is trying to use `layout-bp` who belongs to `@angular/flex-layout/mq`

```
@import '@angular/flex-layout/mq';

.top-bar {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

.start-over {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2.5px;

  .material-icons {
    margin-right: 5px;
    transform: scalex(-1);
  }

  span {
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  &--mobile {
    display: none;

    .material-icons {
      transform: scalex(-1) translate(12px, -12px);
    }
  }
}

@media screen {
  @each $br in ('xs', 'sm') {
    @include layout-bp($br) {
      .start-over {
        margin-right: 8px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think the issue is because it's trying to find the mq.scss file inside `src/app/` when the file is in `node_modules`

To run the project I use `yarn start:consumer` or `yarn start`
This command does the following:
   1) Build the project.
   2) Run the files in the `dist` folder with: `node dist/app.js`

Below I copy the `postcss.config.js`, `webpack.config.js`, `webpack.common.js`, `webpack.dev.js` and `package.json`.

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    parser: 'postcss-scss',
    plugins: {
        "postcss-import": {},
        'postcss-each': {},
        'postcss-at-rules-variables': {},
        'postcss-simple-vars': {},
        'precss': {},
        'postcss-functions': {},
        'cssnano': {},
        autoprefixer: {
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        },
    }
};
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'prod':
  case 'production':
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.prod')({env: 'production'});
    break;
  case 'test':
  case 'testing':
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.test')({env: 'test'});
    break;
  case 'dev':
  case 'development':
  default:
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev')({env: 'development'});
}
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');
/*
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');

const buildUtils = require('./build-utils');

/*
 * Webpack configuration
 */
module.exports = function (options) {
    const METADATA = Object.assign({}, buildUtils.DEFAULT_METADATA, options.metadata || {});
    const supportES2015 = buildUtils.supportES2015(METADATA.tsConfigPath);
    const entry = {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
        'main': './src/main.browser.ts'
    };

    return {
        entry: entry,
        resolve: {

            mainFields: [ ...(supportES2015 ? ['es2015'] : []), 'browser', 'module', 'main' ],
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss'],
            modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],
            alias: buildUtils.rxjsAlias(supportES2015)
        },
        module: {

            rules: [

                {
                    test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                    loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.component\.(sass|scss)$/,
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')],
                    use: [
                        'to-string-loader',
                        { loader: 'css-loader', options: {importLoaders: 1, modules: true } },
                        'postcss-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: 'raw-loader',
                    exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'assets/[name].[hash].[ext]',
                    }
                 },
                {
                    test: /\.(eot|woff2?|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
                    use: 'file-loader'
                }

            ],

        },
        plugins: [

            new DefinePlugin({
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                'process.env.ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                chunksSortMode: 'none'
            }),
            new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
                sync: /inline|polyfills|vendor/,
                defaultAttribute: 'async',
                preload: [/polyfills|vendor|main/],
                prefetch: [/chunk/]
            }),
            new LoaderOptionsPlugin({}),
        ],
        node: {
            global: true,
            crypto: 'empty',
            process: true,
            module: false,
            clearImmediate: false,
            setImmediate: false
        }

    };
};
```

**webpack.dev.js**

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge'); // used to merge webpack configs
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js'); // the settings that are common to prod and dev
const webpack = require('webpack');

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const NamedModulesPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NamedModulesPlugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const HotModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/HotModuleReplacementPlugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const buildUtils = require('./build-utils');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ngToolsWebpack = require('@ngtools/webpack');

/**
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = function (options) {
    /* HERE ARE DEFINED THE CONST USED BELOW. I REMOVED THEM BECAUSE THEY CONTAIN SENSITIVE INFORMATION OF THE PROJECT */

    const METADATA = Object.assign({}, buildUtils.DEFAULT_METADATA, {
        host: HOST,
        port: PORT,
        ENV: ENV,
        STYLES_URL: 'http://' + HOST + ':' + PORT + '/styles',
        HMR: helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot'),
        PUBLIC: process.env.PUBLIC_DEV || HOST + ':' + PORT,
        API_BASE_URL: API_BASE_URL,
        GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
        API_KEY: API_KEY,
        THUMBOR_BASE_URL: THUMBOR_BASE_URL,
        STRUCTURE: STRUCTURE,
        WIDGET_BASE_URL: WIDGET_BASE_URL,
        WEBPAGE_BASE_URL: WEBPAGE_BASE_URL,
        SOCKETS_URL: SOCKETS_URL,
        AUTH_BASE_URL: AUTH_BASE_URL,
        FIREBASE_API_KEY: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        FIREBASE_APP_ID: FIREBASE_APP_ID,
        FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID: FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
    });

    return webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV, metadata: METADATA}), {
        mode: 'none',
        devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
        output: {
            path: '/',
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
            sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',
            chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',

            library: 'ac_[name]',
            libraryTarget: 'var',
        },
        plugins: [

            new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                debug: true,
                options: {}
            }),
            new DefinePlugin({
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                'API_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(API_BASE_URL),
                'GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY': JSON.stringify(GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY),
                'API_KEY': JSON.stringify(API_KEY),
                'THUMBOR_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(THUMBOR_BASE_URL),
                'STRUCTURE': JSON.stringify(STRUCTURE),
                'WIDGET_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(WIDGET_BASE_URL),
                'WEBPAGE_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(WEBPAGE_BASE_URL),
                'SOCKETS_URL': JSON.stringify(SOCKETS_URL),
                'AUTH_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(AUTH_BASE_URL),
                'FIREBASE_API_KEY': JSON.stringify(FIREBASE_API_KEY),
                'FIREBASE_APP_ID': JSON.stringify(FIREBASE_APP_ID),
                'FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID': JSON.stringify(FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID),
                'process.env': {
                    'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                    'API_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(API_BASE_URL),
                    'API_KEY': JSON.stringify(API_KEY),
                    'THUMBOR_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(THUMBOR_BASE_URL),
                    'STRUCTURE': JSON.stringify(STRUCTURE),
                    'WIDGET_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(WIDGET_BASE_URL),
                    'WEBPAGE_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(WEBPAGE_BASE_URL),
                    'SOCKETS_URL': JSON.stringify(SOCKETS_URL),
                    'AUTH_BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(AUTH_BASE_URL),
                    'FIREBASE_API_KEY': JSON.stringify(FIREBASE_API_KEY),
                    'FIREBASE_APP_ID': JSON.stringify(FIREBASE_APP_ID),
                    'FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID': JSON.stringify(FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID)
                }
            }),
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: 'src/index.html',
                title: METADATA.title,
                chunksSortMode: function (a, b) {
                    const entryPoints = ["inline", "polyfills", "sw-register", "styles", "vendor", "main"];
                    return entryPoints.indexOf(a.names[0]) - entryPoints.indexOf(b.names[0]);
                },
                metadata: METADATA,
                inject: 'body'
            }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                    {from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets'},
                    {from: 'src/styles/loading.css', to: ''}
                ]
            ),

            new ngToolsWebpack.AngularCompilerPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: helpers.root('tsconfig.json'),
                mainPath: helpers.root('src/main.browser.ts'),
                sourceMap: true,
            })

        ],

        devServer: {
            port: METADATA.port,
            host: METADATA.host,
            hot: METADATA.HMR,
            compress: true,
            public: METADATA.PUBLIC,
            historyApiFallback: true,
            disableHostCheck: true,
            watchOptions: {
                // if you're using Docker you may need this
                // aggregateTimeout: 300,
                // poll: 1000,
                ignored: /node_modules/
            },

            overlay: {
                errors: true,
                warning: false
            },
            setup: function (app) {
                // For example, to define custom handlers for some paths:
                // app.get('/some/path', function(req, res) {
                //   res.json({ custom: 'response' });
                // });
            }
        },

        node: {
            global: true,
            crypto: 'empty',
            process: true,
            module: false,
            clearImmediate: false,
            setImmediate: false
        }
    });
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.26.0",
  "description": "An angular project",
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "angular2",
    "angular5",
    "webpack",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "My Self",
  "homepage": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "sideEffects": [
    "src/polyfills.browser.ts"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build:aot:prod": "yarn clean:public && cross-env yarn webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "yarn clean:public && yarn clean:dist && yarn server:build:prod && yarn build:aot:prod && yarn minify:externalcss",
    "clean:public": "yarn rimraf ./public/**.js ./public/**.css** ./public/**.html ./public/assets ./public/**.json",
    "clean:dist": "yarn rimraf dist",
    "clean:install": "yarn set progress=false && yarn install",
    "clean": "yarn cache clean --force && yarn rimraf node_modules doc coverage dist ./public/**.js ./public/**.css** ./public/**.html ./public/assets",
    "node": "node",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:build": "tsc -p ./server",
    "server:dev": "yarn server:build && cross-env NODE_ENV=development tsc-watch -p ./server --outDir ./dist --onSuccess \"yarn server\"",
    "server:dev:consumer": "yarn server:build && cross-env NODE_ENV=development tsc-watch -p ./server --outDir ./dist --onSuccess \"yarn server\"",
    "server": "node dist/app.js",
    "start": "yarn server:dev",
    "start:vm": "yarn server:dev:vm",
    "start:consumer": "yarn server:dev:consumer",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "watch:test": "yarn test --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "webdriver:update:stock": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --chrome false --gecko false --standalone false",
    "webdriver:update:new": "yarn webdriver:update:stock && ./node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager update --gecko false --standalone false && yarn webdriver:move && yarn webdriver:update:replacement",
    "webdriver:move": "mv ./node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/update-config.json ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack:bundle:analyzer": "webpack-bundle-analyzer",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
    "minify": "minify",
    "minify:externalcss": "yarn minify --output ./public/loading.css ./src/styles/loading.css",
    "snyk-protect": "snyk protect",
    "prepublish": "npm run snyk-protect",
    "precommit": "yarn test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular-mdl/core": "git+ssh://git@github.com/mtuduri/angular2-mdl.git#v6.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.23",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~2.1.3",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.4.3",
    "@ngxs/storage-plugin": "^3.4.3",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.4.3",
    "angular2-notifications": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",
    "bluebird": "3.5.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "config": "1.29.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "express": "4.16.2",
    "express-healthcheck": "^0.1.0",
    "express-winston": "2.4.0",
    "firebase": "^7.2.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "helmet": "3.10.0",
    "honeybadger": "1.2.1",
    "honeybadger-js": "^0.5.2",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "newrelic": "^4.9.0",
    "ng2-odometer": "^1.1.3",
    "ngx-loadable": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-mask": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-take-until-destroy": "^5.4.0",
    "postcss": "7.0.17",
    "postcss-at-rules-variables": "^0.1.10",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^9.0.2",
    "postcss-each": "^0.10.0",
    "postcss-easy-import": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-import-resolver": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-load-config": "^2.1.0",
    "postcss-mixins": "^6.2.3",
    "postcss-modules-tilda": "^1.0.1",
    "postcss-node-modules-replacer": "^0.0.1",
    "postcss-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-prefix-selector": "1.7.2",
    "postcss-sass": "^0.4.2",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-url": "^8.0.0",
    "precss": "^4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",
    "sass-lazy-compiler": "git+ssh://git@github.com/theappraisallane/sass-lazy-compiler.git#1.1.1",
    "semver": "^5.6.0",
    "snyk": "^1.163.1",
    "stylelint": "^12.0.1",
    "tal-ng-dcp": "git+ssh://git@github.com/theappraisallane/tal-ng-dcp.git#^1.4.64",
    "tal-ng-fileupload": "git+ssh://git@github.com/theappraisallane/tal-ng-fileupload.git#^1.0.5",
    "tal-ng-sockets": "git+ssh://git@github.com/theappraisallane/tal-ng-sockets.git#0.0.22",
    "tal-ng-translate": "git+ssh://git@github.com/theappraisallane/tal-ng-translate.git#1.2.3",
    "typescript-rest": "1.2.2",
    "winston": "2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^7.2.1",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "@pact-foundation/karma-pact": "^2.1.9",
    "@pact-foundation/pact": "^7.0.1",
    "@pact-foundation/pact-web": "^7.0.2",
    "@types/bluebird": "3.5.20",
    "@types/config": "0.0.33",
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/express": "4.11.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.4",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
    "@types/helmet": "0.0.37",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/material-design-lite": "^1.1.15",
    "@types/newrelic": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/nock": "^9.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.5",
    "@types/request": "^2.47.0",
    "@types/semver": "^5.5.0",
    "@types/sinon": "^4.1.3",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.6.30",
    "@types/webpack": "^3.8.8",
    "@types/winston": "2.3.7",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.3",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "codecov": "^3.1.0",
    "codelyzer": "^4.2.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "css-to-string-loader": "^0.1.3",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "cucumber": "^5.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "find-root": "^1.1.0",
    "gherkin-lint": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3",
    "husky": "^3.0.9",
    "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "~3.0.1",
    "istanbul-merge": "^1.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "jasmine-promise-wrapper": "^0.0.3",
    "jasmine-ts": "^0.3.0",
    "jsonlint-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.11",
    "minifier": "^0.8.1",
    "ng-router-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "nock": "^9.2.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "nyc": "^11.5.0",
    "parse5": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-comment": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.0",
    "postcss-discard-comments": "^4.0.2",
    "postcss-functions": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-inline-comment": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^4.2.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "postcss-sassy-mixins": "^2.1.0",
    "postcss-scss": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-strip-inline-comments": "^0.1.5",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.6.2",
    "sass-lint": "^1.12.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "sinon": "^4.3.0",
    "sinon-express-mock": "^2.0.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.3",
    "string-replace-loader": "~2.1.1",
    "sugarss": "^2.0.0",
    "tal-protractor-common": "git+ssh://git@github.com/theappraisallane/tal-protractor-common.git#1.4.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tsc-watch": "^1.0.16",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "typedoc": "^0.11.1",
    "typescript": "3.2.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.4",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.7",
    "webdriver-manager-replacement": "^2.0.2",
    "webpack": "~4.41.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~3.9.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.1.2",
    "webpack-pwa-manifest": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 8.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 5",
    "yarn": ">= 1.0.0"
  },
  "nyc": {
    "include": [
      "server/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "server/**/*.spec.js"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "text-summary",
      "json",
      "html"
    ],
    "extension": [
      ".ts",
      ".tsx"
    ],
    "all": true,
    "report-dir": "./coverage/server"
  },
  "snyk": true
}
```

Comment: command you are using for building the project? How you have setup the yarn for this project?

Comment: To run the project I use: ```yarn start:consumer``` or ```yarn start```
This command do the following:
1) Build the project.
2) Run the files in the ```dist``` folder with: ```node dist/app.js```.

There I updated my question with this information and I include the ```package.json```

Comment: That doesn't look right to me. It looks like WebPack is trying to resolve a CSS import. It doesn't look like your running `node-sass` here at all.

Comment: @Reactgular, yes you are right ```node-sass``` is not being used. It's there because I used to use ```sass-loader``` and ```node-sass``` is required if you use ```sass-loader``` but I removed ```sass-loader``` because now I am using ```postcss-loader``` to handle the ```.scss``` files.

Comment: Okay. It depends upon the loader for how it resolves `node_module` references. `sass-loader` required a prefix of `~` and `node-sass` can use a prefix of `@`. I've never used `post-css-loader` but check if it requires a prefix, because I don't see one in the question examples.

Comment: Now I add the ```scss``` code of the ```app.component``` that it's trying to use the ```scss``` file in ```node_modules```.  I have tried with ```~ ```, ```node_modules/```, ```../../../node_modules/``` but nothing result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in the question, the problem was the compiler was failing to compile the `scss` files of the components when they try to import an `scss` file from `node_modules`.

I resolved it with `sass-loader` applying the following rule for `scss` in the **webpack.config.common.js**:

```
        {
            test: /\.component\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
            use: [
                'to-string-loader',                  
                'css-loader',
                'postcss-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        sassOptions: {
                            importer: url => {
                                if (url.startsWith('@angular/')) {
                                    return {
                                        file: path.resolve(`./node_modules/${url}`),
                                    };
                                }
                                return null;
                            },
                        },
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

If I will have to import another library from node_module I should add another else if statement:

Example, let's say I have a custom library my-library in node_modules and I want to access to: `node_modules/my-library/style.scss` so I have to add the following `else if` statement:

```
   {
        test: /\.component\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: [
            'to-string-loader',                  
            'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                    sassOptions: {
                        importer: url => {
                            if (url.startsWith('@angular/')) {
                                return {
                                    file: path.resolve(`./node_modules/${url}`),
                            };
                            else if (url.startsWith('my-library/')) {
                                    return {
                                        file: path.resolve(`./node_modules/${url}`),
                                    };
                                }
                            return null;
                        },
                    },
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

With that, my project works again. Also it compiles with `build` and `serve`.

Finally, in my **postcss.config.js** I only need:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('autoprefixer')
    ]
}
```